# Is it's possible to connect ArcGIS Server for WorkGroup to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, arcgis, arcgis-server

I know that ArcGIS for Server for workgroup can work only with SQL Server Express. But is it possible to connect with full version of SQL Server? I need to test how it would work with big DB.

Comment: If you already know that X can *only* work with Y, there's not much sense in asking wether X can *also* work with Z. That is, it appears you already answered your own question.

Comment: I am not sure with it. I do not know is it's license incomparability, or it's future restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ArcGIS Server for Workgroup will not work with anything else but, SQL Express. You can upgrade your Workgroup license to Enterprise but, it's going to cost you quite a bit. I wound up doing this so, that I wasn't limited by SQL Express.